# Unlimited fill region

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw a figure with unlimited fill region as the attachment figure. Thank you![image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "unlimited fill regions"? Do you want to fill the whole page? Because somewhere the filling has to stop. Or you you simply want a filled region without a drawn boundary line?

Comment: are you looking for \pagecolor{green} ?

Comment: If you mean "fill without drawing an edge", as in the regions between lines in your graph, then this is by default the way tikz's `\fill` works, unless you also add a `[draw]` option to it.

Answer (score 9):

This is possible via `fillbetween` library of [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots). Consult the manual for putting the labels and removing ticks etc. You can also search this site for examples.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
    axis equal,
    grid=both,
    xlabel=A,ylabel=B,
    no marks,
    domain=-10:10,
    xmax=5,xmin=-5,ymax=5,ymin=-5,samples=3]% lines don't need too many samples
\addplot+[name path=o,draw=none] {0};
\addplot+[name path=a] {-1*x};
\addplot+[name path=b] {1/6*x};
\addplot+[name path=c] {1/2*x};
\addplot+[name path=d] {3*x};

\addplot[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=blue] fill between[of=o and b] ;
\addplot[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=red] fill between[of=b and c] ;
\addplot[pattern=vertical lines,pattern color=green] fill between[of=c and d] ;
\addplot[pattern=horizontal lines,pattern color=orange] fill between[reverse=false,of=a and d] ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Once you are comfortable, you can produce the same with a for loop.

Comment: I'm guessing what the OP means by "unlimited" is that the outer (large r) boundary is not a regular shape like a rectangle in your MWE, but rather just a sector hatched out to some amorphous radius.  Think "schematic" rather than "graph".  Of course, I could be mistaken in interpreting the OP.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Indeed it might be that too. But you can draw the graph larger and add a `\clip <whatever closed curve here>` in the end of the code to clip everything with a one liner.